# Admob with Android: unable to parse android:configChanges in manifest

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add ads to my Android app using Admob, but have hit a brick wall.  Admob says it requires the following from `logcat`

```
E/Ads     (26043): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.
E/Ads     (26043): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.
E/Ads     (26043): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.
```

However, the Android SDK in Eclipse on Ubuntu fails to be able to parse the following,

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

When I go to the activity and select the attribute in the manifest, the last three items show 'Unrecognized flag'.

I want to add ads in on Android 1.6 (API level 4), but these attributes don't exist until API levels in the teens.  How do I reconcile this?

Comment: Yup, it is so strange that the AdMob page says it can run on 1.5 and above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AdMob SDK v4.3.1 was released late last night.  The SDK requires these new configChanges for tablet optimization, but these configChanges are only available in Honeycomb and above.

You will need to download Android SDK Version 3.2 or above, and then set `target=13` or above in your project.properties file to compile against the new SDK version.  It will still support Android 1.5 devices and above, and that can be controlled by the minSdkVersion in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out I also needed to update all my Android SDK components.  After that, and changing the target with the minSDK it seems to work.

Comment: I have some problems with testing on a 2.3 device.
I can either compile with target of android-13 or android-14 - but then unable to test on my device or I can keep the target of android-8 (this is my base as my phone was initially a 2.2 device) and then unable to compile due to issues with Manifest.XML ... how to get both - compiling fine and application testable on 2.3 ??

Comment: In your manifest, you can set the `android:minSdkVersion` to the minimum version your app supports, and set the `android:targetSdkVersion` to the maximum version you've tested your app against.  Any devices higher than the target version will go into compatibility mode to the target version.  The `target=13` in your default.properties (now called project.properties) is just the Android SDK you are compiling against.